# Simple function using pointers causing a memory error

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, pointers

My code is a mixture of Objective-C and C. I've simplified the code below, but it still produces the same error. In the Objective-C file:

```
CGFloat r,g,b = 0.5;
CGFloat x,y,z = 0.0;

foo(r, g, b , &x, &y, &z);
```

And the C part (an imported C file):

```
void foo(CGFloat R, CGFloat G, CGFloat B, CGFloat *X, CGFloat *Y, CGFloat *Z) {

    *X = 5;
    *Y = 5;
    *Z = 5;

}
```

The error happens when assigning to what's in one of the pointers - it says EXS_BAD_ACCESS. What am I missing (or not understanding correctly?). I'm assuming that it's fine to have separate .c and .m files in the same project... it seems to build fine anyway.

Comment: what does debugger say? what is content of `X/Y/Z`?

Comment: @BryanChen the debugger doesn't say anything, and X/Y/Z seem to be set to random values. Just noticed it's not crashing on 64 bit, only on 32 bit... weird.

Comment: how did you call it? with real code

Comment: @BryanChen the above code is what I'm currently using and I still get the error.

Comment: don't you have to set all variables to something? x=y=z = 0.0 instead of x,y,z = 0.0? Objective-c will complain if you don't initialize variables and then try to access their memory.

Comment: give the full error message. log value of `X/Y/Z`, also log `*X/*Y/*Z`(which may cause crash if they are invalid pointers). change `CGFloat` to float/double

Comment: Try `*X = (CGFloat)5;`

Comment: @BryanChen I've noticed something very interesting... It actually gets past the first assign to *X. BUT if I look at values in the calling function, x is unchanged, whereas B and alpha have just been set to weird values. So *X = is somehow changing alpha and B. Now I'm even more confused hah...

Comment: move the function implementation to the same file your call the function. it sounds like calling conversion somehow unmatched. It is likely that `CGFloat` is `double` in one file and `float` in another

Comment: @BryanChen hah! Found the problem. 
#ifndef CGFLOAT_DEFINED
#define CGFLOAT_DEFINED 1
typedef double   CGFloat;
#endif was included in the c file (which I didn't create). Thanks..!

Comment: Note, that your initializations may not do what you think they do.  That first line initializes `b` to 0.5, but does nothing with `a` and `b`.  Similarly, the second line only initializes `z`.

Answer (score 0):

In the header for my c source file, there were a few rogue lines declaring CGFloat as a double. Deleted, and replaced all CGFloat's in my C file with floats.

Answer (score -1):

You have to initialize memory for all your variables. Try this instead:

```
CGFloat r = 0.5, g = 0.5, b = 0.5;
CGFloat x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

foo(r, g, b , &x, &y, &z);
```

In Objective-c if you try to access the memory location of a variable, i.e. `&x`, without first assigning a value to it, it will give you a `EXS_BAD_ACCESS`. However, r,g, and b don't need to be initialized (but will have garbage data if you don't).

Comment: It will in Objective-c if you try to access the memory location of a variable, i.e. `&x` without first assigning a value to it.

Comment: really?? how ObjC differ to C in this case?? I can't see how get address of uninitialised variable can cause crash. It is not even undefined behaviour (I think).

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an optimization, but this exact thing happened to me the other day when trying to do RGB to HSV conversions.

Comment: @Jason Sorry, Jason, but that is just completely wrong.  You can take the address of a variable on the stack any time you want, whether it has been initialized or not.